# I am unable to create values in my firestore when signing up with email and password with react-native-firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I am unable to create values in the firestore when creating an account with firebase authentication. I am using react-native-firebase. Here is my Sign up function:

```
const signUp = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const userCredential = await auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      const uid = userCredential.user.uid;

      console.log(`User with UID ${uid} created successfully`);

      await firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).set({ email, exerciseCount: 0, workoutCount: 0 });

      console.log(`Firestore document created for user with UID ${uid}`);

      dispatch({ type: UserAction.SignUp, payload: userCredential.user });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error creating user: ${error.message}`);
    }
  };
```

I get the following error in my terminal:

```
 LOG  User with UID i6zrc74FZXgye2Td6vGvTedu9nk1 created successfully
 ERROR  Error creating user: undefined is not a function
```

There's not anything wrong with the dispatch as i commented that out and still got the same error. I feel like maybe this isn't even something wrong with my code at this point. Seems similar to the docs.

Comment: can u pls share your imports and firebase packages version?

Comment: Instead of `catch (error)` and then logging the message, consider simply `throw error` again - so that you get the entire stack trace of the error. Even better would be to not `catch` the error at all, and letting the caller handle it.